# How to use external api access tokens without exposing them to the user?

Tags: reactjs, access-token

Sorry if this might be a bit of a trivial question, but I wanna be sure and couldn't exactly find a definitive answer online.

I am writing a small app that uses Mapbox, and I am using [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) for it. They require the access token on the client side, so they suggest using an environment variable. My question is would it be okay to simply create a .env file in the front-end folder and put the variable there?

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can use a .env, just make sure its in your gitignore so its never pushed up with your code, in this case its not ever accessible to the user, its simply in your local environment

Comment: Will do, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get away from revealing API keys on the front end. If someone wants to dig around in your source code, they will find them.

However, you should always configure any API key that is visible on the Internet to be restricted to specific referrers, i.e. the domain of your website.

Usually this is done during creation of an API key through your provider's dashboard.

For Mapbox, you can read the documentation on restricting API tokens [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/#url-restrictions). It states:

> You can make your access tokens for web maps more secure by adding URL restrictions. **When you add a URL restriction to a token, that token will only work for requests that originate from the URLs you specify.** Tokens without restrictions will work for requests originating from any URL.

*(emphasis my own)*

---

> They require the access token on the client side, so they suggest using an environment variable. My question is would it be okay to simply create a .env file in the front-end folder and put the variable there?

There are two reasons one uses environment variables in front-end development:

1. As a convenience, to keep environment-specific configuration removed from source code.
2. To keep sensitive information out of source code. You shouldn't commit API tokens or other similarly sensitive details to your version control.

Using environment variables in front-end code will not to keep their values secret from the end user. Whatever the value of an environment variable is at build time will be visible in the compiled output.